# Connecting Javascript properties to Java object

Tags: javascript, java, dom, nashorn

## The Problem

I am trying to feed a Java object into a script that would normally operate on the Document Object Model (DOM) of a web page. For the most part this functions as intended. However I have encountered a problem when dealing with attributes/properties of the DOM elements.

A particular property chain of interest is `somediv.firstChild.href`. What I can't figure out is how to get the `firstChild` property value dynamically. The simplest way I can think of at the moment is to use `source.replaceAll("firstChild", "firstChild()");` to force the `firstChild` property to invoke the function `firstChild()` instead. However this will eventually open up a new can of worms.

## The Question

How do I define an object that can be passed to a javascript function that can be operated on via the DOM?

## Background

#### Learnings from C#

Before diving into Java I had learnt C#. In C# the concept of setters and getters is quite prevalent. If this interface method were available in Java my problem would be solved.

```
public string firstChild {
    get { return this.getFirstChild(); }
    set { this.setFirstChild(value); }
}
```

#### Current Implementation

The script is currently invoked by wrapping it in a function where I can pass in the `window` and `document` Java objects into the function's workspace.

`document` is a special top-level version of `SpoofedDomElement` (that extends it) but is functionally identical to the sample shown below. `window` is another object with minimal functions that handle event listeners.

**Javascript (snippet) to operate on DOM**

```
var somediv = document.createElement('div');
somediv.style.display = "block"
somediv.innerHTML="<a href='/mywork/server/test.html'>The Test Server Homepage</a>";
var linkvalue = somediv.firstChild.href;
```

This snippet is stored as the string `theOriginalSource` and used in the next section.

**Java code to evaluate Javascript**

```
String wrappedSource = "var scriptToInvoke = function(window, document){"
    + "\n" + theOriginalSource // from above
    + "\n};"

Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("scriptToInvoke", window, document);
```

This snippet wraps the javascript snippet so that I can pass in objects to use as `window` and `document`.

**Java classes that spoof DOM elements**

```
public class SpoofedDomElement {
    public SpoofedDomElement firstChild;
    public String id;
    public String innerHtml;
    public String href;
    public SpoofedStyleProperties style = new SpoofedStyleProperties();
    public String tagname;
    ...
}

public class SpoofedStyleProperties {
    public String background = "transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0% auto padding-box border-box";
    public String color = null;
    public String display = "inline";
}
```

The above classes handle irrelevant parts of the code just fine (such as the assignment `somediv.style.display = "block"`). But it starts to fall apart when handling the values of `firstChild` or `innerHtml` when either value is changed.

## Past Work

**N.B.** I include this section in all my questions to document what I have tried for future SO users who get here by Google. This might help someone reach a solution by aiding brainstorming.

#### Attempted Solutions

I have attempted to use a framework ([HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)) to evaluate the Javascript. But I couldn't control which Javascript snippets were executed.

#### Potential Solutions

The following are questions that I am currently researching to find a solution. If I find anything I will report back.

- Is there a way to emulate C# getter/setter behaviour in Java?
- Can Javascript evaluate `firstChild` as a function?
- Is there a way to create a wrapper within Javascript with getter/setters that can invoke my Java class's functions?
- Is there an Apache Commons library for Nashorn (or similar) that isn't as heavy as the complete simulation frameworks (such as [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/))?

Comment: I feel a bit lost because I think this might be an XY problem. Also, I think there are too many questions for...well, one question - at least some of them may be split out. For number 1 - yes, in fact, getters and setters aren't _emulated_ but the `get/set` syntax in C# is just sugar hiding how you "normally" (in other languages, including Java) do it. #2 - yes you probably can evaluate it as a function but no, you shouldn't, since it isn't - it's a property. #3 I don't think there is. #4 I have no idea. Each of these can also be its own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to implement friendly access of script objects from Java code as well as  trying to provide script-friendly API on top of java library/libraries.

For the first part [ script object access from Java ]

Apart from javax.script.Invocable interface, you can use JSObject. Nashorn exposes script objects as instances of jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject/.ScriptObjectMirror

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/nashorn/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/ScriptObjectMirror.html

For the second part [ friendlier access of Java objects from scripts ]

You can write script friendly wrappers in script itself using "JSAdapter".

Doc and Example:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-JSAdapterconstructor

If you'd prefer to do in Java, you can implement your own jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.JSObject/.AbstractJSObject.

Doc and Example:

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-jsobject

Other nashorn specific script extensions may also be used to trap unknown property/method access in per object basis:

**noSuchProperty** hook in any script object:

[https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-**noSuchProperty**](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-__noSuchProperty__)

**noSuchMethod** hook in any script object:

[https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-**noSuchMethod**](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-__noSuchMethod__)

Object.bindProperties:

There script API extension can be used to bind properties of one object to another - the source object could be a Java object as well.

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-Object.bindProperties

With jdk9, there is more flexible inter-language linking possible with Dynalink API [ http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/276 ]

See also:

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/dynamic_linker_api_for_the

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/writing_pluggable_dynalink_linker_and

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/nashorn_javascript_access_to_python

There are dynalink samples "samples/dynalink" directory of Nashorn OpenJDK repository:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/4a6ee1185fc8/samples/dynalink

Comment: Thanks for these. I'll look into them

Comment: It was achievable by overriding the `setMember` and `getMember` functions of the `ScriptObjectMirror` or `JSObject` (inherits `ScriptObjectMirror`). Cheers. Apologies for the late answer marking.